# SQL tournament date generator

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am trying to create a tournament where in each team will play each other once both home and away.

I want to generate a date so that each Friday the teams will play one another

TempExampletable shows what the end result will look like with each team playing once per week.

TempExampletable2 shows the data I currently have and what I will be using to generate the date.

```
DROP TABLE TempExampletable;
DROP TABLE TempExampletable2;

CREATE TABLE TempExampletable(
Home VARCHAR(100),
Away VARCHAR (100),
    Playing DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO TempExampletable VALUES
('Team 1', 'Team 2', '2017/12/01 17:30:00'),
('Team 1', 'Team 3', '2017/12/08 17:30:00'),
('Team 1', 'Team 4', '2017/12/15 17:30:00'),
('Team 2', 'Team 1', '2017/12/22 17:30:00'),
('Team 2', 'Team 3', '2017/12/15 17:30:00'),
('Team 2', 'Team 4', '2017/12/08 17:30:00'),
('Team 3', 'Team 1', '2017/12/29 17:30:00'),
('Team 3', 'Team 2', '2018/11/05 17:30:00'),
('Team 3', 'Team 4', '2017/12/01 17:30:00'),
('Team 4', 'Team 1', '2018/01/05 17:30:00'),
('Team 4', 'Team 2', '2017/12/29 17:30:00'),
('Team 4', 'Team 3', '2017/12/22 17:30:00')

CREATE TABLE TempExampletable2(
Home VARCHAR(100),
Away VARCHAR (100),
    Playing DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO TempExampletable2(Home, Away) VALUES
('Team 1', 'Team 2'),
('Team 1', 'Team 3'),
('Team 1', 'Team 4'),
('Team 2', 'Team 1'),
('Team 2', 'Team 3'),
('Team 2', 'Team 4'),
('Team 3', 'Team 1'),
('Team 3', 'Team 2'),
('Team 3', 'Team 4'),
('Team 4', 'Team 1'),
('Team 4', 'Team 2'),
('Team 4', 'Team 3')

SELECT * FROM TempExampletable2 ORDER BY Playing ASC;
SELECT * FROM TempExampletable ORDER BY Playing ASC;
```

Comment: Format your code properly.  Ask a specific, narrow question (i.e. what's not working with your code?).  Better yet, read [ask] and then come back and try again.

Comment: Can you add your expected output please?

Comment: Thanks, it displayed like that on my phone but when I submitted it was stripped out

Comment: Self join perhaps?

Comment: The expected outcome is as above TempExampletable. TempExampletable2 is the data I currently have and I want a way of generating the date so that it isn't input manually like in the first table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. Please format the date as you like or you can insert into a datetime column

```
WITH teams AS
(SELECT Home, Away, 
       row_number() over(order by Home, Away) - 1 AS r_num
  FROM TempExampletable2 )
SELECT Home, Away, DATEADD(week, r_num, '2017/12/01 17:30:00') AS Playing
  FROM teams
  ORDER BY Playing ASC;
```

Output

```
Home    Away    Playing
Team 1  Team 2  2017-12-01T17:30:00Z
Team 1  Team 3  2017-12-08T17:30:00Z
Team 1  Team 4  2017-12-15T17:30:00Z
Team 2  Team 1  2017-12-22T17:30:00Z
Team 2  Team 3  2017-12-29T17:30:00Z
Team 2  Team 4  2018-01-05T17:30:00Z
Team 3  Team 1  2018-01-12T17:30:00Z
Team 3  Team 2  2018-01-19T17:30:00Z
Team 3  Team 4  2018-01-26T17:30:00Z
Team 4  Team 1  2018-02-02T17:30:00Z
Team 4  Team 2  2018-02-09T17:30:00Z
Team 4  Team 3  2018-02-16T17:30:00Z
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I want multiple teams to play on the same day though rather than one per week if you look at the example dates in the first table team 1 plays team 2 in week one. While Team 3 plays team 4 also in week 1.

Comment: sure, how do you decide which team plays on which day? Is there an algorithm?

Comment: No thats the point of this question, each team should play once per week such as shown in the example data. therefore there should be two games per week. A team should never play twice a week.

Answer (score 0):

You know that because there are 4 teams involved, there are 2 matchups per week. If, within a given week, you schedule one matchup you know the second matchup cannot involve either of the participants from the first. (`Team 1` can't play `Team 2` and `Team 3` at the same time, regardless of `Home`/`Away` decisions) This scenario makes it difficult to handle this in a set based approach where you'd be making use of Recursive CTE's or other methods.

The above is why I have written a double nested `while` loop to schedule the tournament season. The first loop for going week by week, and the second scheduling a matchup in each iteration.

**Sample Data:**

I simplified the sample data down to a list of the teams, and later create the matchups shown in your `TempExampletable2`

```
create table #team_table
    (
        Team char(6) not null
    )

insert into #team_table
values ('Team 1')
    , ('Team 2')
    , ('Team 3')
    , ('Team 4')
```

**Answer:**

```
create table #matchups
    (
        Home char(6) not null
        , Away char(6) not null
    )

create table #schedule
    (
        Home char(6) not null
        , Away char(6) not null
        , Playing datetime not null
    )

insert into #matchups
select h.Team as Home
, a.Team as Away
from #team_table as h
cross join #team_table as a
where 1=1
and h.Team <> a.Team

declare @bgn_dt datetime = '2017-12-01 17:30:00'
    , @tm_cnt int = (select count(*) from #team_table)
    , @i int = 1
    , @j int
    , @j_max int
    , @wk_cnt int
    , @rnd int
    , @cur_dt datetime;

set @wk_cnt = ((@tm_cnt * (@tm_cnt - 1)) / 2)

set @j_max = (@tm_cnt / 2) --games in a week

while @i <= @wk_cnt
begin --while i

    set @cur_dt = dateadd(d, 7 * (@i - 1), @bgn_dt)

    set @j = 1

    while @j <= @j_max
    begin

        ; with sched_teams as
            (
                select s.Home as Team
                from #schedule as s
                where 1=1
                and s.Playing = @cur_dt
                union all
                select s.Away as Team
                from #schedule as s
                where 1=1
                and s.Playing = @cur_dt         
            )
        insert into #schedule
        select top 1 m.Home
        , m.Away
        , @cur_dt as Playing
        from #matchups as m
        left join sched_teams as sh on m.Home = sh.Team --same team can't play 2 games in a single week
        left join sched_teams as sa on m.Away = sa.Team --same team can't play 2 games in a single week
        left join #schedule as s on m.Home = s.Home --can't play the same matchup twice
                                and m.Away = s.Away
        where 1=1
        and sh.Team is Null
        and sa.Team is Null
        and s.Home is Null
        and s.Away is Null
        order by m.Home asc
        , m.Away asc

        set @j += 1

    end

    set @i += 1

end --while i

select *
from #schedule
order by Home
, Away
```

The `order by` on the `insert...select` statement is only there to force the output to be the same as the expected output specified in `TempExampletable`.